# Prove that B is positive semidefinite if AB+BA is positive semidefinite and A is positive definite

Tags: positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ and $B$ be real symmetric matrices such that $A$ is positive definite and $AB+BA$ is positive semidefinite. Is $B$ positive semidefinite?

Comment: Consider $B^T(AB+BA)$

Comment: Hi @DougM. Kindly clarify, Both A and B are symmetric as given.

Comment: I didn't even notice that it said that both were symmetric.  $B^T(AB + BA) = B^TAB + B^TBA,  B^TAB$ is positive definite if $A$ is positive definite $B^TB$ is positive semi-definite as is $B^TBA$ and the sum of positive semi-definite matrices is positive semi-definite.  The product of $B^T$ and a positive semi-definite matrix produces a positive semi-definite matrix.  Which means that $B^T$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: So if XY is positive semidefinite and Y is positive semidefinite then X is positive semidefinite?

Comment: Actually this is where the we need to call on the fact that they are symmetric.  The product of positive semi-definite matrices with real eigenvalues are positive semi-definite.  And symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues.

Comment: Shouldn't $B^TAB$ just be positive semidefinite since $B$ can be equal to the zero matrix? The proof still holds though.